# Can other people commit to my Git repo?

Tags: git, version-control

I've created a few free Git repositories for sharing my projects online. But, I use that code locally, so could other people mess with it?

I have created the repositories online, on their Website, then I cloned them to my laptop, and then I copy-pasted all my relevant project's files in there. After that I `git add .`'ed, `git commit -a`'ed and `git push`'ed.

When I say that I plan to use that code locally, I mean that I plan to import the Python module from the repo directory on my laptop.

Comment: Gee, I don't know... where do you host this repository? How is it configured?

Comment: Depends if you set it to private or not...which service is it?

Comment: Where have you created these "free repositories"? How do you expose them? What do you mean by "use that code locally"? What do you mean by "other people mess with it"? Please word your question more accurately. As it stands now, it doesn't make any sense. The short answer to the title of the question is - No, people can only commit to their own clones of a repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have `write` access to the repository, then can `commit` code to it.  You can then `pull` in the changes that others have committed.  With `git` you often work in branches, and if you're the owner or the admin, you can choose to merge the code commit with the `master` branch, or, to entirely dismiss the commit if you think it's not useful.

Also, not all `git` repositories are visible or accessible to everyone.  This depends on the way you have configured it.

Here's a good [introductory article](https://wincent.com/wiki/Git_repository_access_control) that explains access controls in git.